Prove that for $x,y,z$ positive integers the form of $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+yz+zx}$ can't be equal to 3.
Because it is positive integers so I can multiply both side by $(xy+yz+zx)$
I have tried to use completing square, like below
$(3x-3y)^2+(3y-3z)^2+(3z-3x)^2=12x^2+12y^2+12z^2$
But in above form, it didn't help much.
Then I tried using AM-GM inequality but get nothing.

Please include the question in the body of the post.

Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1958433p13536501

If there is a solution in integers, not all zero, to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 3yz - 3zx - 3xy = 0$  then dividing by $\gcd(x,y,z) $  gives a solution with variables not all zero, and $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1,$  variables not all zero. Next:  if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 3yz - 3zx - 3xy \equiv  0  \pmod {25},$   then all three $x,y,z \equiv 0 \pmod 5.$  So, this contradicts the assumption of an integer solution with $xyz \neq 0$  This is one way of writing Fermat's Infinite Descent   that I like.  The quadratic form is thus "anisotropic"  over the $5-adic $ numbers. See Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms

Actually, it follows that the prime $2$ also works; try $\pmod 4$  that may be enough.

prove that for any positive integers $(x)$ $(y)$ and $(z)$, the expression $(\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{xy + yz + zx}$) cannot be equal to 3.
Allow me to provide some preliminaries for this proof:
Lemma 1:(Algebraic Identity) For any real numbers $(a)$, $(b)$, $(c)$, the following identity holds:
$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca = \frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2)$
Lemma 2: (Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality) For all real numbers $(a)$, $(b)$, $(c)$,
$$
(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2) \geq (a + b + c)^2.
$$
{Proof by Contradiction:}
Assume, otherwise, that the given expression is equal to 3.
$$
\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{xy + yz + zx} = 3.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $(xy + yz + zx)$ $\rightarrow$:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3(xy + yz + zx).
$$
Applying Lemma 1, we rearrange the terms:
$$
\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx.
$$
$\rightarrow$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2) = 2(xy + yz + zx). 
$$
Since each squared term is non-negative, if $(\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2) = 0)$, it implies $(x = y = z)$. Substituting $(x = y = z)$ into the original assumption:
$$
\frac{3x^2}{3x^2} = 1,
$$
which contradicts the original assumption.
For the case where $((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 > 0)$, the left-hand side remains strictly positive and cannot equate to $(2xy + 2yz + 2zx)$
Thus, by contradiction, $(\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{xy + yz + zx} \neq 3)$ for any positive integers $(x)$, $(y)$, and $(z).

Why the case where $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2>0$ cannot equate to $2xy+2yz+2zx$ ? I think you should prove that claim.

Assume the case of $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2 \gt 0$ $\forall$ x,y,z at least 2 must be strictly distinct to hold true.
$(x-y)^2 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2$
$(y-z)^2 = y^2 - 2yz + z^2$
$(z-x)^2 = z^2 - 2zx + x^2$
Consider the term $(x-y)^2$:
In order for it to contribute $2xy$ to the sum, we'd need:
$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = 2xy$
Simplifying this gives: $x^2 - 4xy + y^2 = 0$
This would imply $x = 2y$, which contradicts the assumption that x, y are distinct.
Similar reasoning can be applied for the rest of the squared difference terms accordingly. If we didn’t have >0 then aye plenty of intersects.
